# How to create PDF in Gnuplot using a specific font?

Tags: pdf, fonts, gnuplot

To make a PDF plot which uses a particular font, for example this:
`/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf`

I set in gnuplot:

`set term pdfcairo font "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf"`

But the resulting PDF has a basic sans font in it, not the one I choosed.

By looking at [this documentation](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/fonts.html) it seems that Cairo terminal uses fontconfig which replaces Comic font with Dejavu one, which is totally different.
I've also tried to convert from truetype to pfa:

`ttf2pt1 -a -e -W 0 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf - > comic.pfa'`

and then using the pfa in the postscript terminal:

`set term postscript eps enhanced fontfile "< cat comic.pfa"`

(at the end I use `epstopdf` to make the PDF).

But here it seems that postscript terminal probably must use only type1 fonts, and the resulting PDF is the same as above.

Is there a way to force a specific font?

Comment: I was tempted not not answer to not support the use of Comic Sans ;) But have you tried the simplest variant `set terminal pdfcairo font "Comic Sans MS"`? That works for me.

Comment: Oh my god! It works, thank you! But how does the other way don't?!

Comment: btw, actually I'm not going to use Comic Sans, I just used it as example because it's well recognisable ;)